# Jquery Dropdown Populate data

Tags: jquery

I have a two Drop Down List In a jsp page,And  i am select the first dropdown items then we want to populate the Second dropDown List Items From Data BAse,

This is my jQuery Ajax Code:-

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: 'name=' + dept,
                async: false,
                url: "master/loginCreateUser.jsp?emp=1",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);                      
                }
              });
            }
```

and this is my loginCreateUSer.jsp Page:-

```
       ArrayList<String> emp = new  ArrayList();
      emp =  new UserRights().showEmp(s1);
```

I have All data For a Second drop Down lIst in a ArrayList emp,then How can we retrieve the this Arraylist emp in a first success function. And how can we add this data the second dropdown list,

this is my dropDown List

```
     <select name="deptName" id="deptName" style="height:25px; width: 190px;"  onChange="viewEmp(this.value)"> 
                            <option value="0" selected >(please select:)</option> 
                            <%
                                int i = 0;
                                int a = new DBDepartment().getDepartment().size();
                                 while (a != 0) {
                            %>
                            <option><%= new            DBDepartment().getDepartment().get(i).getDeptname()%></option>
                            <% 
                                    a--;
                                    i++;
                                 }
                            %>
                        </select>

  <select name="empEvents" id="empName" style="height:25px; width: 190px;"> 
  </select>
```

Comment: firstly attach the ajax functionality to onchange event of first drop down list . then create a variable in js to hold all the values of second drop down list like this .`<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJspVariable = '<%= myJspVariable %>';
</script>`. finally construct the options for the select tag and update the content of select element.` var itemval= '<option value="OT">OT</option>';

     $("#SelItem").html(itemval);` this should go into your success section of ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Add this to your success callback function:

```
for(var item in data){
   $("#empName").append("<option>" + data[item] + "</option>");
}
```

This is assuming the data you return in your ajax function is a list of strings. If it is a list of objects then replace data[item] with data[item].variableName.

Comment: sir i appericiate your Ans,still i am not able to return list,plz give me some idea,Thnx Sir

Comment: @BipinBangwal Can you provide a link to your page or a fiddle or something?